# How to mock a signal to python in shell?(Not use kill)

Tags: python, shell

In shell, how to send a signal to python to stop it? **I can get the pid of python process**. Notice that for some reason about coding check, I can't use `kill` command.

This is my python.py:

```
#!/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import signal
import sys

is_exit = False


def some_task():
    global is_exit
    while not is_exit:
        print("do task")


def handle_stop(signal, frame):
    global is_exit
    print("receive exit signal and do close")
    is_exit = True
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_stop)

    t = threading.Thread(target=some_task, args=())
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

    alive = True
    while alive:
        alive = alive or t.isAlive()
```

In this python file, I catch `signal.SIGINT` to do stop. And I test it successfully by Ctrl+C and kill. Can you give me some advise on mocking a signal(like SIGINT) or other signal?.

What I want to do is like:

```
CMD $pid MOCK_SIGNAL
```

Comment: There are only a few kinds of signals. You might wanna use `SIGUSR1` to emulate what you're trying to do

Comment: By the way you can send a signal from python itself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill

Comment: @DroidX86 Any signal if python's signal can accept is ok. Can shell or python send SIGUSR1 to another process?

Comment: @G.yx `kill -SIGUSR1 12345` where 12345 is the process ID (pid) of the process which is going to receive the signal. You can also use `killall` or `pkill` to send signals to processes based on their name or other criteria.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Sorry, I can't use `kill` for the coding check. And I'm asking if os.kill() is the best way. Thanks

Comment: @G.yx you asked how to do it from the shell. `kill` sends signals from the shell. Maybe you have the wrong assumption that `kill` is only for killing processes? Anyway, if `kill` is specifically out of the question, there´s still `pkill` and others.

Comment: @G.yx `kill` is a system call that can be used to send any signal to any process. The `kill` command & `os.kill` are both wrappers on top of it. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html

Comment: @blubberdiblub Thanks for you explanation. I do have the wrong assumpytion about kill. I will try it!

Comment: @DroidX86 Thanks a lot. I understand it. I will use kill/os.kill().